# Getting X and Y instead of horizontal/vertical size in layout properties of Swing JPanel

Tags: java, swing, hide, jpanel, shrink

When if a panel has layout properties like horizontal size and vertical size, then I'm able to hide the panel and space used by panel is also shrinking.  But If the panel has layout properties like X and Y,  then I'm able to hide the panel, But space used by panel is left blank and not removed.

How to make the space shrink, when the panel is hidden?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just hide the component and then revalidate/repaint the container? This will effectively cause the container to "shrink."

Comment: Is there Any Option in Netbeans to Revalidate or repaint container  or need to it using Source code underlying it?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's easier to develop UIs manually IMHO. You may have to delve into the source code yourself.